# Keep CSS styling for printed pages using Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, printing, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I'm trying to print an invoice I've created using BS3 as a framework. Now I want to print it and I have found out that the @media print entry in the CSS makes some adjustments. I have completely removed these but I still get DIVs with transparent backgrounds and the likes. What I ultimately want, is an identical page to be printed. Is that possible?

How might I go about to do this? I can't seem to be able to troubleshoot this any further.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your original css in media print query.

Comment: This is a really low quality answer. What is a "media print query", as you put it.

Comment: This didn't help. And it seems like a really bad way of going about it too.